# org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusUserException exception when running maven project for app engine

Tags: java, spring, maven, google-app-engine, jpa

I am trying to run my maven project on google app engine .My project uses datanucleus-core and datanucleus-api-jpa for persistence and when I run mvn clean appengine:devserver I get the below error

```
[INFO] org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusUserException: Found Meta-Data for class com.fixit101.controller.model.entity.Category but this class is not enhanced!! Please enhance the class before running DataNucleus.
[INFO]  at org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager.initialiseClassMetaData(MetaDataManager.java:2570)
[INFO]  at org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager.initialiseFileMetaData(MetaDataManager.java:2521)
[INFO]  at org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager.initialiseFileMetaDataForUse(MetaDataManager.java:1117)
[INFO]  at org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager.loadPersistenceUnit(MetaDataManager.java:963)
[INFO]  at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.JPAEntityManagerFactory.initialiseNucleusContext(JPAEntityManagerFactory.java:754)
[INFO]  at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.JPAEntityManagerFactory.initialise(JPAEntityManagerFactory.java:417)
[INFO]  at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.JPAEntityManagerFactory.<init>(JPAEntityManagerFactory.java:380)
[INFO]  at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.PersistenceProviderImpl.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProviderImpl.java:91)
[INFO]  at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:150)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:96)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$6.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1615)
[INFO]  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1562)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:743)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:548)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:136)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:255)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:288)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AutomaticInstanceHolder.startUp(AutomaticInstanceHolder.java:26)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule.startup(AbstractModule.java:87)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.Modules.startup(Modules.java:105)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.doStart(DevAppServerImpl.java:258)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.access$000(DevAppServerImpl.java:47)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:213)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:211)
[INFO]  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:211)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:277)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:48)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.run(DevAppServerMain.java:219)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:210)
```

My project pom.xml is as below

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<groupId>com.fixit101</groupId>
<artifactId>fixit-app</artifactId>

<properties>
    <appengine.app.version>1</appengine.app.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <spring.version>4.1.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>

<prerequisites>
    <maven>3.1.0</maven>
</prerequisites>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Compile/runtime dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine.orm</groupId>
        <artifactId>datanucleus-appengine</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
    <artifactId>datanucleus-core</artifactId>
    <!-- version>3.1.0-m3</version -->
    <version>3.1.4</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
   </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
        <artifactId>datanucleus-api-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
        <artifactId>geronimo-jpa_2.0_spec</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-agent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.5</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <!-- for hot reload of the web application-->
    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>display-dependency-updates</goal>
                        <goal>display-plugin-updates</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>

        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <forkMode>once</forkMode>
                <argLine>
                    -javaagent:${settings.localRepository}/org/springframework/spring-agent/${spring.version}/spring-agent-${spring.version}.jar
                </argLine>

            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <executable>java</executable>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>-Xmx1000m</argument>
                    <argument>-javaagent:${project.build.directory}/agents/spring-agent.jar</argument>
                    <argument>-classpath</argument>
                    <classpath/>
                    <argument>fixit-app</argument>
                </arguments>

            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
                <webResources>
                    <!-- in order to interpolate version from pom into appengine-web.xml -->
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>**/*.jar</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                        <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
                <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/datanucleus*.jar</packagingExcludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.10</version>

            <configuration>

                <enableJarClasses>false</enableJarClasses>
                <!-- Comment in the below snippet to bind to all IPs instead of just localhost -->
                <!-- address>0.0.0.0</address>
                <port>8080</port -->
                <!-- Comment in the below snippet to enable local debugging with a remove debugger
                     like those included with Eclipse or IntelliJ -->
                <!-- jvmFlags>
                  <jvmFlag>-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n</jvmFlag>
                </jvmFlags -->
            </configuration>

        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: _"Found Meta-Data for class com.fixit101.controller.model.entity.Category but this class is not enhanced"_ is very clear. You need to bytecode enhance your classes BEFORE runtime, and include the enhanced versions of the classes at runtime

Comment: You are missing the pre-build class enhancement. Are you using eclipse? Idea? plain maven?

Comment: My project is a spring maven project with datanucleus-jpa libraries .What is the bytecode enhancement and how do we do the same ?

Comment: I am using intellij idea with plain maven

Comment: Can bytecode enhancement be done through maven ?

Answer (score 0):

After deep analysis I had found the way to enhance the JPA classes using maven as below

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-datanucleus-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${datanucleus.jpa.version}</version>

                <configuration>
                    <api>JPA</api>
                    <mappingIncludes>**/entity/*.class</mappingIncludes>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                </configuration>

                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
                        <artifactId>datanucleus-core</artifactId>
                        <version>${datanucleus.jpa.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>enhance</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
     </plugin>
```